# Conditional copying two tables SQL Server 2008 on a range

Tags: sql-server-2008, datatable, conditional-compilation

I have two tables and require the first table to be updated as the third screen shot.
[image: This is the first table. The VON is the first value of the range. This value is picked up from the second table till the BIS value is reached. While the BIS value is reached in the second table, the RANGE column is updated with the values between VON and BIS values.]
This is the first table. The VON is the first value of the range. This value is picked up from the second table till the BIS value is reached. While the BIS value is reached in the second table, the RANGE column is updated with the values between VON and BIS values.

The second table contains sequentially listed values from 01 to 99 and alphanumeric values such as A1, A2 etc.

[image: This is the required output.]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExpandRows()
Dim rgLastCell As Range
Dim rgThisRow As Range
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
Dim wsNewSheet As Worksheet
Dim rgThisRecord As Range
Dim intVon As Integer
Dim intRes As Integer
Dim dblCopyRowNumber As Double

Set wsMaster = ActiveSheet
Set wsNewSheet = Worksheets.Add(after:=wsMaster)
wsNewSheet.Name = "Output"
Set rgLastCell = GetLastCell(wsMaster)
dblCopyRowNumber = 2

wsMaster.Rows(1).Copy wsNewSheet.Range("A1")
wsmaster.columns.autofit

For Each rgThisRow In Range("A2:A" & rgLastCell.Row)
    Set rgThisRecord = wsMaster.Range(Cells(rgThisRow.Row, 1).Address, Cells(rgThisRow.Row, rgLastCell.Column).Address)
    Debug.Print rgThisRecord.Address
    If IsNumeric(rgThisRecord(8)) Then

        intVon = rgThisRecord(8).Value
        intRes = rgThisRecord(9).Value

        While intVon <= intRes
            rgThisRecord.Copy wsNewSheet.Range("A" & dblCopyRowNumber)
            wsNewSheet.Cells(dblCopyRowNumber, 11).Value = intVon
            dblCopyRowNumber = dblCopyRowNumber + 1
            intVon = intVon + 1
        Wend
    Else
        rgThisRecord.Copy wsNewSheet.Range("A" & dblCopyRowNumber)
        dblCopyRowNumber = dblCopyRowNumber + 1
    End If
Next

Set rgLastCell = Nothing
Set rgThisRow = Nothing
Set wsMaster = Nothing
Set wsNewSheet = Nothing
Set rgThisRecord = Nothing

End Sub
```

and this is the find last cell function:

```
Function GetLastCell(ByVal wsCurrentSheet As Worksheet) As Range
Dim rgLastRow As Range
Dim rglastColumn As Range
Dim rgLastCell As Range

Set rgLastRow = wsCurrentSheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
Set rglastColumn = wsCurrentSheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

Set GetLastCell = wsCurrentSheet.Cells(rgLastRow.Row, rglastColumn.Column)

Set rgLastCell = Nothing
Set rgLastRow = Nothing
Set rglastColumn = Nothing

End Function
```

Hope that helps.